# Assign gene names from another dataframe based on SNP position and gene start/end coordinates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes: one with a list of SNPs and their positions, and another with a list of genes and their start and end coordinates. **Using dplyr**, I'd like to add a column to the SNP dataframe that has the name of the gene that each SNP falls within (i.e. the position of the SNP is on the same chromosome, and falls between the start/end coordinates, inclusive, of the gene).

If a SNP doesn't fall within any gene coordinates, it should get "NA" in the gene column. The chromosome number between SNP and gene must match. For example, even though the position of the second SNP falls within the start/end coordinates of Gene4, that is not a match because they are on different chromosomes.

SNP dataframe:

```
CHR  POS  REF  ALT
01   5    C    T
01   10   G    A
02   5    G    T
02   15   C    A
02   20   T    C
03   10   A    G
03   20   C    T
```

GENE dataframe:

```
CHR  START  END  GENE_NAME
01   2      8    Gene1
01   12     20   Gene2
01   25     30   Gene3
02   10     18   Gene4
02   25     35   Gene5
03   5      15   Gene6
```

Desired Output:

```
CHR  POS  REF  ALT  GENE_NAME
01   5    C    T    Gene1
01   10   G    A    NA
02   5    G    T    NA
02   15   C    A    Gene4
02   20   T    C    NA
03   10   A    G    Gene6
03   20   C    T    NA
```

Again, I'd like to accomplish this using dplyr. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think the desired output should contain `Gene6` for the SNP at CHR03:10, not `Gene5`.

Comment: @akrun thanks, I added one, too, and there are many dplyr solution below.

Comment: Oops, you're right. It should be Gene6. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `map2_chr` from `purrr` is to filter the `GENE` dataframe based on `POS` and `CHR` from `SNP` and select the corresponding `GENE_NAME`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

SNP %>%
   mutate(GENE_NAME = map2_chr(POS, CHR, function(x, y) {
       inds = x >= GENE$START & x <= GENE$END & y == GENE$CHR
      if (any(inds)) GENE$GENE_NAME[which.max(inds)] else NA
 }))

#  CHR POS REF ALT GENE_NAME
#1   1   5   C   T     Gene1
#2   1  10   G   A      <NA>
#3   2   5   G   T      <NA>
#4   2  15   C   A     Gene4
#5   2  20   T   C      <NA>
#6   3  10   A   G     Gene6
#7   3  20   C   T      <NA>
```

In base R, this can be written using `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y) {
   inds = x >= GENE$START & x <= GENE$END & y == GENE$CHR
   if (any(inds)) GENE$GENE_NAME[which.max(inds)] else NA
}, SNP$POS, SNP$CHR)

#[1] "Gene1" NA      NA      "Gene4" NA      "Gene6" NA
```

**data**

```
SNP <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), POS = c(5L, 
10L, 5L, 15L, 20L, 10L, 20L), REF = c("C", "G", "G", "C", "T", 
"A", "C"), ALT = c("T", "A", "T", "A", "C", "G", "T")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

GENE <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), START = c(2L, 
12L, 25L, 10L, 25L, 5L), END = c(8L, 20L, 30L, 18L, 35L, 15L), 
GENE_NAME = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks to all that helped answering this problem. I accepted this answer because I think it will be the most scalable to the large dataframes I'm working with.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with `dplyr`. You simply expand `gene` dataframe based on `START` and `END` and then `left_join` with `snp` -

```
snp %>% 
  left_join(
    gene %>% 
      group_by(CHR, START, END) %>% 
      mutate(
        POS = list(seq(START, END))
      ) %>% 
      unnest(),
    by = c("CHR", "POS")
  ) %>% 
  select(CHR, POS, REF, ALT, GENE_NAME)

  CHR POS REF ALT GENE_NAME
1   1   5   C   T     Gene1
2   1  10   G   A      <NA>
3   2   5   G   T      <NA>
4   2  15   C   A     Gene4
5   2  20   T   C      <NA>
6   3  10   A   G     Gene6
7   3  20   C   T      <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using `non-equi` join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(snp)[gene, GENE_NAME := GENE_NAME, on = .(CHR, POS >= START, POS <= END)]
snp
#   CHR POS REF ALT GENE_NAME
#1:   1   5   C   T     Gene1
#2:   1  10   G   A      <NA>
#3:   2   5   G   T      <NA>
#4:   2  15   C   A     Gene4
#5:   2  20   T   C      <NA>
#6:   3  10   A   G     Gene6
#7:   3  20   C   T      <NA>
```

---

Or with `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_left_join(snp, gene, by = c("CHR", "POS" = "START",
   "POS" = "END"), match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>% 
   select(CHR = CHR.x, POS, REF, ALT, GENE_NAME)
#  CHR POS REF ALT GENE_NAME
#1   1   5   C   T     Gene1
#2   1  10   G   A      <NA>
#3   2   5   G   T      <NA>
#4   2  15   C   A     Gene4
#5   2  20   T   C      <NA>
#6   3  10   A   G     Gene6
#7   3  20   C   T      <NA>
```

---

Or an option with `rap`

```
library(rap)
snp %>% 
   rap(GENE_NAME = ~ filter(gene, CHR ==  !!CHR, START <= POS, END >= POS) %>% 
          pull(GENE_NAME)) %>% 
   mutate(GENE_NAME = replace(GENE_NAME, !lengths(GENE_NAME), NA)) %>% 
   unnest
#  CHR POS REF ALT GENE_NAME
#1   1   5   C   T     Gene1
#2   1  10   G   A      <NA>
#3   2   5   G   T      <NA>
#4   2  15   C   A     Gene4
#5   2  20   T   C      <NA>
#6   3  10   A   G     Gene6
#7   3  20   C   T      <NA>
```

#### data

```
snp <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), POS = c(5L, 
10L, 5L, 15L, 20L, 10L, 20L), REF = c("C", "G", "G", "C", "T", 
"A", "C"), ALT = c("T", "A", "T", "A", "C", "G", "T")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

gene <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), START = c(2L, 
12L, 25L, 10L, 25L, 5L), END = c(8L, 20L, 30L, 18L, 35L, 15L), 
    GENE_NAME = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
    "Gene6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```